# Assemble 32 bit mode instructions in elf64 format with GCC (gas/as)

Tags: assembly, gcc, x86, osdev, gnu-assembler

I'm trying to port an OS development tutorial from NASM Intel syntax to GAS (gcc/as).

I translated to AT&T syntax with no problems, except for one directive: `bits 32`. This is necessary because the processor is still in protected mode (32 bit mode) at the multiboot entry point, but we're building a 64-bit kernel as a 64-bit ELF executable.

With NASM, I would put the `bits 32` directive at the beginning of my file (boot.asm), and then assemble with:  `nasm -f elf64 boot.asm -o boot.o`

---

I found online that i could replace `bits 32` directive with the `-m32` option for GCC (equivalent to `as --32`):

```
gcc -c -m32 boot.S -o boot.o
```

However this turns the output format to `elf32`, when I wanted `elf64` to link with compiler-generated 64-bit code, since the entry point switches to long mode.

How can I solve this? Is there any other way to use 32 bit instructions without `-m32` or a way to specify the mode separately from the output format with GCC and/or the GNU assembler?

*link of the tutorial: https://os.phil-opp.com/multiboot-kernel/*

Comment: In general you want 32 bit code to be in an elf32, what's the problem with that? Anyway, if you insist, you can use `.code32`.

Comment: Refer to the [GNU as manual](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/) for details.  You should read it carefully before using the assembler.

Comment: @Jester In the tutorial the 32 bit code is put in an elf64, and I assume that is because we later have to link it with 64 bit code (that will naturally be in an elf64) when we transition to real mode, and you can't link elf32 and elf64 together.

Comment: @SamFF This is indeed one of the few sensible use cases for `.code32`.  I am writing this because in almost all cases, using this directive is an indication that you have misconfigured your toolchain and should seek a different solution to your problem.

Comment: Real mode needs `.code16`, and would require fully leaving long mode, not just 16-bit sub-mode of it.  In a process (or UEFI application) that starts in 64-bit mode, 32-bit mode would more typically be achieved with a far jmp to a 32-bit code segment without leaving long mode, i.e. entering "compat" sub-mode of long mode rather than full 64-bit mode.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64#Operating_modes

Comment: That tutorial is about having a 32-bit protected-mode entry point in a 64-bit kernel.  At no point would you ever want to switch the CPU to real mode.  Instead you want to switch to long mode!  I assume that was a typo, and you meant long mode.  Anyway, yes, this entry-point code is the use case for `.code32` or `bits 32`, since you want to link the whole thing as a 64-bit executable.

Comment: Yes, I meant long mode. But yes, that works, thanks!

Comment: Also FYI, GAS supports `.intel_syntax noprefix` (for MASM-like syntax).  You'd still have to translate any symbol references that don't involve a register, though, e.g. NASM `mov eax, foobar` becomes `mov eax, OFFSET foobar` to get the address.  Fortunately `mov eax, [foobar]` works the same in both, but GAS doesn't have a "default rel" so 64-bit code would want to use `mov eax, [rip + foobar]`.

Answer (score 3):

I found what I was missing:

The `bits 32` directive should simply be replaced with `.code32` and it works.